# webpack bundle fails on reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I think the problem is not with react router configuration but my index.html not being able to detect my script? This is my error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

this is my webpack config code:

```
const compiler = webpack({
  entry: ['whatwg-fetch', path.resolve(__dirname, 'js', 'index.js')],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
      },  
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ],
  },
  output: {filename: 'app.js', path: '/'},
});

const app = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  contentBase: '/public/',
  proxy: {'/graphql': `http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`},
  publicPath: '/js/',
  stats: {colors: true},
  historyApiFallback: {
    index: 'index.html' 
  } 
});
```

and my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="relay">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.11/semantic.min.css">
    <title>Relay • TodoMVC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Force `fetch` polyfill to workaround Chrome not displaying request body
      // in developer tools for the native `fetch`.
      self.fetch = null;
    </script>
    <script src="http://localhost:4000/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Help?

Comment: can you set the `historyApiFallback` to true?

Comment: @GovindRai thanks, working now

Comment: added a richer explanation..take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the HTML5 History API, the index.html page will likely have to be served in place of any 404 responses. Enable this by passing:

```
historyApiFallback: true
```

It's actually a pretty important concept and one you should grasp since this is a major component of any single page application (SPA). Also I feel you should take a deep dive into your webpack config file when you get the chance.

Here's a better, enriching explanation on the historyApiFallback option:

> Single Page Applications (SPA) typically only utilise one index file
>   that is accessible by web browsers: usually index.html. Navigation in
>   the application is then commonly handled using JavaScript with the
>   help of the HTML5 History API. This results in issues when the user
>   hits the refresh button or is directly accessing a page other than the
>   landing page, e.g. /help or /help/online as the web server bypasses
>   the index file to locate the file at this location. As your
>   application is a SPA, the web server will fail trying to retrieve the
>   file and return a 404 - Not Found message to the user.

Two great resources: [Webpack Dev Server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) and [connect-history-api-fallback documentation](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback).