# React Router Dom with parameter not working properly?

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my code on route config:

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path='/(home)?' component={TodoListHomePage} />
   <Route exact path='/profile/:userId' component={TodoListProfilePage} /> 
   <Route  path='/login' component={SignUpAndLogin} /> 
</Switch>
```

everything works fine but the path with param is weird, on first click it works fine, path e.g.

> http://localhost:4000/Profile/597c1f43a87ca40d38f79a68

on the 2nd click it concatenates Profile something like this:

> http://localhost:4000/Profile/Profile/597c1f43a87ca40d38f79a68

and on an on e.g.

> http://localhost:4000//Profile/Profile/Profile/Profile/597c1f43a87ca40d38f79a68

This is my function invoked when Profile link is clicked:

```
handleProfileClick = (e, {name}) => {
      this.setState({ activeItem: name }); 
      this.props.history.push(name.concat('/'.concat(this.props.viewer._id.toString())));
}
```

Comment: You are using relative paths. Just add a `/profile` before the concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative paths. Just add a `/` before the concatenation.

```
handleProfileClick = (e, {name}) => {
      this.setState({ activeItem: name }); 
      this.props.history.push("/profile/" + this.props.viewer._id.toString());
}
```

Comment: thanks it works now, but when I reload it, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). what might be the cause?

Comment: Hmm... I cleared up your `concat` operations.. try it with updated code?

Comment: yes it's working, now, but I just had another eror occur when I try to reload, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), but when I click it, it works great, just on the profile route(in question) it fails on reload but on other route it's fine.

Comment: do you have your code on github? Not sure what the issue could be, if it's a 404 that means the route hasn't been defined.. what url does it show upon reload? Maybe open a new question and link your TodoListProfilePage component code in that question?

Comment: I had done my search and thinks it's a webpack bundle but i'm not sure, here is my question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657732/webpack-bundle-fails-on-reload I'd really appreciate